# Nodejs and sequelize : Error .find is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am a nodeJs developer, I failed to get the list of users, when I tested my code on postman it gives me the error below:
User.find is not a function
The following is my user.js file

```
'use strict';
 const {
  Model
 } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model  {

    static associate(models) {
       }
  }
  User.init({
    username: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email:  {
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password:  {
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    role: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName:'users',
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

and this is where it's imported/required

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user');
router.route('/getUser').post((req, res) => {
    User.find({})
      .then(users => res.json(users))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ', err));
});
```

Comment: Btw I created the user and I did the login and everything passed successfully

Comment: First of all sequelize models has no such method as `find`. You have to use either [`findAll`](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-finders/#findall) or `findOne`

Comment: Okey ! I tried findAll({}) and same problem findAll is not a function

Comment: import error. import your User as let User = require('../models').user;

Comment: Thank you Abhay , it's okey it works, the error was in the import as you said

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work, I did as you told me but it gives me back:

> sequelize id not defined

Also I don't think that the problem is in the model because I have used it before and  in the login I used `.find` and it worked without any problem!
this login code :

```
router.post('/login', async (req,res,next) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email }});
  if (user) {
    const password_valid = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password);
    if (password_valid) {
      token = JWT.sign({
        isLogin: true,
        "id": user.id,
        "email": user.email,
        "username": user.username
      },"12345678");
      res.status(200).json({token :token});
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({isLogin : false, error: "password incorrect" });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({isLogin : false, error :"User does not exist"});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The user.js file that you provided is exporting a function that create the User class (and not actually the User model class)

Did you already init this class elsewhere and you are importing the wrong file ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question, can you explain it better please ?

Comment: Given the user.js you provided, if you require this file like so `const User = require('../models/user');`, you would have to do something like `const UserModel = User(sequelize, DataTypes)`. I suppose you already did this elsewhere and you are not importing the right `User` ?
`